# Curl Command: how do you post a user information in database that will not disappear after stop running with Curl command?

Tags: rest, web, curl, post, get

I created a website that you can just create an account and login with that account, and then I tried to register an account by REST POST method and get the user information by REST GET method with Curl from terminal. But, it seemed that I can only get the user info while running the program. It means that the user I registered with Curl POST disappears from the database after shutting down the program. Is it possible to register an account that remains in the database non-temporarily?

This is the Curl command I used:

`curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{/*some contents*/}' http://<address>/`

Best regards,

Comment: Records don't disappear by default. It's impossible to know why / how without seeing the server-side code.

Comment: So  the website is supposed to keep the user-information after termination of web server even though the info is posted by curl command?

Comment: If the server used a database, yes. If not, it still depends on the server-side code.

Comment: The database in the web application is H2 database.

Comment: That doesn't really matter.